# Define a MongoDB capped collection from a Loopback 4 model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback4

I defined a model in Loopback 4 framework as the following, and I want to specify, if possible, that the collection created in the MongoDB database is capped:

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model({
  settings: {
    strict: false,
    mongodb: {capped: 1024}, // not working
  },
})
export class DbLog extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: string;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
  })
  date: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  level: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  service: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  message: string;

  @property({
    type: 'object',
  })
  metadata?: object;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    default: 1,
    jsonSchema: {
      pattern: '^[0-9]{1}$',
    },
  })
  schemaVersion: number;

  constructor(data?: Partial<DbLog>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface DbLogRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type DbLogWithRelations = DbLog & DbLogRelations;
```

Is there a way to define a capped collection from the framework? I didn't found informations in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create capped Collections as:

```
   @model({
      settings: {
        strict: false,
         mongodb: {capped: true, size: 1024}
      },
    })
```

more information : https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/MongoDB-connector.html#customize-collectionfield-names

Also, FYI the mogodb createCollection() or create() method always takes `

```
capped:<boolean>
size:<number>
max:<number>
```

where size is the maximum size, it is required when you put capped:true
more Information:[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working. db.getCollection('Log').isCapped() still returns false. I know I can create capped collection from the mongo shell but the need is to create it from app code.